# If I get married in 15 yr old without letting know my parents as a girl is it valid?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, talaq

I got married at the age of 15 as a girl in my country where the legal age was 18 but our Kadi made my age 18 and I got married to my boyfriend at that time without letting my parents know. My first question is: was that marriage valid according to Islam?
Later on after 1 year I wanted a divorce from him because I was not able to have any connection physically or mentally I wasn’t feeling anything for him and his actions made me lose everything for him, but he did not want to divorce me but somehow he said talaq 3 times in the text I considered that as a divorce but after 1 year he came again and accused me as his wife still then I filled a divorce against him and considered it as a divorce and freed myself from marriage after a couple of months I got married to another person I am so happy in the marriage now Alhamdulillah..
So now my question is was my first marriage consider as a marriage? If it is was the divorce considered as a divorce? Please help me out

Comment: According to what madhab? Also search the site there are plenty of posts addressing this.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Having that said now to your inquiry: First of all, these are a lot of questions in one post. Secondly, some of these questions already have been addressed on the site, so you should find an answer already. My suggestion to you therefore is the following first check the site for similar questions and answers then ask for each topic which you couldn't clarify a concise question with all the necessary information (see for example the above comment).

Answer (score -1):

السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته
اللهﷻ يبارك فيكي

Marrying a girl without the father’s consent is not considered marriage, but if you  didn't know in that time,  that the father’s consent is required for the marriage, then there is no sin on you or anything.